# Unknown property 'light_weight__Experiment__c StandardController

Tags: apex, visualforce

i am new to salesforce i got exception while working with this.I had use this same extension to my other vf page in this findkeyword method for other page.It is working nice there but here it throws me a exception please don't close or unrated if any wrong in my question.why will you get this exception

my visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Experiment__c" extensions="Search" >
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock title="Member" >
<apex:pageblockButtons >
  <apex:commandButton value="Find" action="{!find}"reRender="SearchList"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>
<apex:pageblocksection >
<apex:inputfield value="{!Experiment.Name}"/>
</apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:pageblock>
<apex:pageblock id="SearchList" title="Member List"  >
<apex:pageBlocktable value="{!memList}" var="memLst" >
<apex:column title="Select" > 
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!memLst.checked}" ></apex:inputcheckbox>
</apex:column>
<apex:column value="{!memLst.themem.Name}" title="Member Name" />
<apex:column value="{!memLst.themem.light_weight__email__c}" title="E-       
Mail Id"/>
<apex:column value="{!memLst.themem.light_weight__mobile__c}" 
title="Mobile Number"/>
</apex:pageBlocktable>   
<apex:pageblockButtons >
<apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!Del}" 
reRender="SearchList"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>      
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

My extension

```
public class Search
{
public String expname {get; set;}
public List<Experiment__c>  expList {get; set;}
public boolean checked{get;set;}
public List<Experiment__c> memTmpLst;
public List<mem> memList {get;set;}
public Experiment__c memb;
String[] selectedNam = new String[]{};
List<String> selectednames =new List<String>();
public List<String> temp {get;set;}
public List<Experiment__c> memDelList;  
public Integer i;

public Search(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{
this.memb = (Experiment__c)controller.getRecord();
}
public void findKeyword()
{
String sql = 'SELECT Name,id FROM Experiment__c WHERE Name LIKE\'%'+expname+'%\' LIMIT 20';
expList = Database.query(sql);
}
public class mem
{
public Experiment__c themem {get; set;}
public Boolean checked{get; set;}
public mem(Experiment__c m,Boolean s)
{
    themem = m;
    checked = s;
  }
}   
public void find()
{
  String nam = memb.Name;
  memList = new List<mem>();
  if(memList == null)
  {
    memList = new List<mem>();
  }  
  String sql = 'SELECT Name,light_weight__mobile__c,light_weight__email__c FROM Experiment__c WHERE Name LIKE\'%'+nam+'%\'';
  memTmpLst = Database.query(sql);
  for(Experiment__c m:memTmpLst)
  {
    mem me = new mem(m,false);
    memList.add(me);
  }    
  }   

public void del()
{
  memDelList = new List<Experiment__c>();
  for(mem m:memList)
  {
    if(m.checked == true)
    {
      if(memDelList==null)
      {
        memDelList = new List<Experiment__c>();
      }
      memDelList.add(m.themem);     

    }             
  }
  Delete memDelList;
  find();
}
}
```

Comment: The Light_Weight_Experiment__c, i don't see this field in your codes. You could submit your actual code which throws errors. Thanks.

Comment: light_weight is my organisation name and Experiment__c is my custom object it is actual code thanks for your reply @SangramKesariRay Kesari Ray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistyped the custom object name `Experiment__c` to `Experiment`.

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!Experiment__c.Name}"/>
```

Comment: hey thanks f or your help i found my mistake in input field i make a mistake by referencing api name.@Jun Ke